# Can someone explain what this ajax code does?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

Can someone explain what this ajax code does?

```
function ajaxProgress(){
 //Math.random() is for bitchy ie to prevent caching the xml.
 $.get('sample.ff?do=progressInfo&type=sampletype&dummy='+Math.random(), { dataType:   'xml'},      function(xml) {
 //if the import is running get infos about the progress...
 if($('/importProgress/running', xml).text() == 'true') {
 //..there are no infos yet, so it was just started..
 if($('/importProgress/progress', xml) == null || $('/importProgress/progress', xml).text() == ''){
 //do something
 }
 ..........
 setTimeout( "ajaxProgress()", 1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is calling itself recursively every second. It sends an AJAX GET request to `Import.ff` and passing 3 query string parameters: `do=progressInfo`, `type=sampletype` and a random number. This random number is appended to the url because GET requests are cached by browsers and by this it ensures that it gets fresh content from the server on each request.

The server itself sends an XML file as response. This XML file contains some nodes like:

```
<importProgress>
    <running>true</running>
    <progress>20</progress>
</importProgress>
```

So the script parses this XML in the success callback of the AJAX request. It tries to get the values of the `running` and `progress` nodes. If `running=true` then it checks whether there's a progress node and does some processing with it. Finally it calls itself 1 second later using the `setTimeout` function. And so on.

So basically this script reports progress from some server operation by polling the server at 1 seconds intervals using AJAX GET requests and parsing the response.

Comment: I have a further question how I can add something like revision in the ajax code which keeps a track when the revision changes then do something.the revision comes from struts action.